# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine

I know that this question was asked multiple times on stackoverflow and I had read almost all of them to solve my error. But my requirement is different from others and all my efforts to accomplish this are in vain.

Developing a web app using Spring MVC , Google Data store and running it on App Engine.

This is my Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

My Web.xml file:

[image: Web.xml file]

My Controller to handle requests:

[image: Controller to handle requests]

My Context file for Dispatcher Servlet:

[image: crudspring.xml]

The Error log generated:

[image: Error log generated]

My project is running on Tomcat server without any errors on another machine. I am encountering this error only on Google App engine.

Help me to sort this error out.

This is the link for my project https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H7z34ZEPr3HniWJsrEaHYIxKUWOf_67P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this program is not executing is , In the dispatcher-servlet.xml , In xsi:schemalocation tag ,  For spring mvc url , I used 4.0 version. That's why this code didn't execute. After removing the version, It executed perfectly